# How can I close a Tmux session and stay connected to Tmux?

Tags: tmux

I typically run Tmux with multiple sessions, usually one per project with multiple windows within.

When I want to throw away a session, I type `exit`. This closes the session, but also detaches from Tmux completely.

How can I stay connected to Tmux?

Comment: Do you want to switch to a different session instead?

Comment: What are you hoping will happen after killing the shell, but keeping `tmux` running?...

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of tmux have a built in option for this: `detach-on-destroy` which defaults to `on`. In your `tmux.conf` add a line:

`set-option -g detach-on-destroy off`

Answer (score 0):

You can make tmux handle a lot of situation using shell scripts/functions .

add this function to your .bashrc/.zshrc

```
function tmux {
  /usr/bin/tmux "$@"
  while     (pgrep tmux); do
          /usr/bin/tmux attach
  done
  exit
}
```

I assume tmux executable file is in /usr/bin

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't this run `pgrep` forever?

I was looking for some sort of Tmux configuration.